# Render src img to HTML

Tags: javascript, dom, selector

I'm trying to get PNGs to render in the renderCardsOnBoard function, but it's not working. Paths to each PNG are in the cardsOnBoard object. I tried to set the src of each PNG, but couldn't get that to work, either. I'm probably not using the right selector or misusing it somehow.

Thank for any help provided.

```
var mainDeck = [];
var selectedSlots = [];
var cardsOnBoard = {
  0: null,
  1: null,
  2: null,
  3: null,
  4: null,
  5: null,
  6: null,
  7: null,
  8: null,
  9: null,
  10: null,
  11: null
};


// Generate random cards
function createCard() {
  var colors = ['green', 'purple', 'red'];
  var shapes = ['cylinder', 'diamond', 'purple'];
  var fills = ['filled', 'outline', 'solid'];
  var sizes = ['1', '2', '3'];
  var colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var shapeIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var fillIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var sizeIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var imgIndex = [];
  return { color: colors[colorIndex], shape: shapes[shapeIndex], fill: fills[fillIndex], size: sizes[sizeIndex], img: '.img/' + colors[colorIndex] + '-' + shapes[shapeIndex] + '-' + fills[fillIndex] + '-' + sizes[sizeIndex] + '.png' };
}

//  Push 81 random cards into the deck
for (let i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
  mainDeck.push(createCard());
}
// console.log(mainDeck);
var div;

// Create the gameboard
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = i;
  div.classList.add("cardslot");
  div.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    selectedSlots.push(this.id);
    this.classList.add('green');
  });
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.textContent = "SET!"
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  removeSelectedCards();
  fillTheCardsOnBoardObject();
  renderCardsOnBoard();
});
document.body.appendChild(button);

// Draw a number of cards from the mainDeck
function draw(num) {
  return mainDeck.splice(0, num);
}
console.log(mainDeck);

function removeSelectedCards() {
  var selectedCards = [];
  selectedSlots.forEach(function (slotId) {
    selectedCards.push(Object.assign({}, cardsOnBoard[slotId]));
    // console.log(selectedCards)
  });
  // Here you would check to see if it is a set

  // To remove them if it is a set, do this
  selectedSlots.forEach(function (slotId) {
    cardsOnBoard[slotId] = null;
  });
  // document.getElementsByClassName('cardslot').classList.remove('green');
}
//something

function fillTheCardsOnBoardObject() {
  for (let key in cardsOnBoard) {
    if (!cardsOnBoard[key]) {
      cardsOnBoard[key] = draw(1)[0];
      console.log("This is the cardsOnBoard object ", cardsOnBoard[key]);
    }
  }
}

function renderCardsOnBoard() {
  var str = '';
  for (let key in cardsOnBoard) {
    document.getElementById(key).textContent = cardsOnBoard[key].shape + cardsOnBoard[key].color + cardsOnBoard[key].fill + cardsOnBoard[key].size;
    document.getElementsByTagName.img = cardsOnBoard[key].image;


  }
  // mainDeck.forEach(function (card) {
  //   str = str + card.color + card.shape + card.fill + card.size + card.img + ' ';
  //   // console.log(str);
  // })
  // document.getElementById('maindeck').textContent = str;
}
console.log("this is mainDeck...", mainDeck);
fillTheCardsOnBoardObject();
renderCardsOnBoard();
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName.img`  what's this meant to be ?

Comment: Change `cardsOnBoard` to `new Array(12).fill(null)`.

Comment: phil - that's the remnant of my last attempt to get it to render

Answer (score 0):

try this.

Remove the line `document.getElementsByTagName.img = cardsOnBoard[key].image;` from `renderCardsOnBoard()`
and add these to where you've removed the mentioned line:

```
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.classList.add("cardImage");
    document.getElementById(key).appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById(key).querySelector('.cardImage').src = cardsOnBoard[key].img;
```